# How to redirect webmail to a new url?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, server, webmail

need to redirect webmail.domain.com to a new url (google mail). i have tried with this code on .htaccess

code:

```
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !https://webmail.domain.com/$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mail.google.com/a/domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but here, the whole site is redirecting to new url. https://domain.com is redirecting. i just want only the webmail url https://webmail.domain.com/ to redirect.

how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "http://" from the Left side of HTTP_HOST string

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webmail.domain.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mail.google.com/a/domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```